# Server Become extremely slow after a few mintues of restart , CPU , Memory is okay

Tags: ubuntu, php, apache-2.4, bitnami

I am using Amazon LightSail with 2CPU, 8G of Ram and 160G of HDD.

CPU load is not more than 20% and Memory is less than 50% , websites both Drupal and Wordpress are very fast at service restart or server reboot but suddenly very slow after a few mintues. This is my htop result:

```
=======================================================
1 [|| 2.0%] Tasks: 113, 1182 thr; 1 running
2 [|| 2.0%] Load average: 0.17 0.13 0.11 
Mem[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| 2.34G/7.80G] Uptime: 06:18:48
Swp[0K/0K]
PID USER PRI NI VIRT RES SHR S CPU% MEM% TIME+ Command
17383 bitnami 20 0 26816 4704 3260 R 2.6 0.1 0:01.35 htop
2157 bitnami 20 0 26672 4188 2796 S 1.3 0.1 5:08.24 htop
16929 daemon 20 0 406M 245M 134M S 0.7 3.1 0:15.41 php-fpm: pool www
16956 daemon 20 0 1731M 99420 54816 S 0.0 1.2 0:00.67 /opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /opt/bitnami/
1528 root 20 0 285M 16368 6700 S 0.0 0.2 0:02.01 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/fail2ban-server -s /var/r
15836 root 20 0 197M 66024 61552 S 0.0 0.8 0:00.23 /opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /opt/bitnami/
17055 daemon 20 0 1720M 35144 27432 S 0.0 0.4 0:00.02 /opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /opt/bitnami/
17098 daemon 20 0 1728M 50428 31152 S 0.0 0.6 0:00.08 /opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /opt/bitnami/
15785 mysql 20 0 3902M 525M 19216 S 0.0 6.6 0:04.63 /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld.bin --defaults-file=/
15797 mysql 20 0 3902M 525M 19216 S 0.0 6.6 0:00.11 /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld.bin --defaults-file=/
16952 daemon 20 0 322M 155M 129M S 0.0 1.9 0:08.11 php-fpm: pool www
16932 daemon 20 0 398M 229M 127M S 0.0 2.9 0:29.88 php-fpm: pool www
15853 daemon 20 0 1728M 53672 31476 S 0.0 0.7 0:00.91 /opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /opt/bitnami/
16930 mysql 20 0 3902M 525M 19216 S 0.0 6.6 0:01.38 /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld.bin --defaults-file=/
17105 mysql 20 0 3902M 525M 19216 S 0.0 6.6 0:00.61 /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld.bin --defaults-file=/
16794 daemon 20 0 1728M 95852 54828 S 0.0 1.2 0:00.07 /opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /opt/bitnami/
1394 root 20 0 269M 6036 5072 S 0.0 0.1 0:00.78 /usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon 
15796 mysql 20 0 3902M 525M 19216 S 0.0 6.6 0:00.03 /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld.bin --defaults-file=/
15849 daemon 20 0 1731M 99420 54816 S 0.0 1.2 0:04.16 /opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /opt/bitnami/
16933 mysql 20 0 3902M 525M 19216 S 0.0 6.6 0:01.20 /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld.bin --defaults-file=/
15851 daemon 20 0 1728M 95852 54828 S 0.0 1.2 0:03.54 /opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /opt/bitnami/
433 root 20 0 12204 4740 1616 S 0.0 0.1 0:04.84 /usr/sbin/haveged --Foreground --verbose=1 -w 1024
16921 daemon 20 0 333M 121M 86616 S 0.0 1.5 0:06.44 php-fpm: pool www
16870 daemon 20 0 1731M 99420 54816 S 0.0 1.2 0:00.01 /opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /opt/bitnami/
16931 daemon 20 0 355M 181M 122M S 0.0 2.3 0:07.41 php-fpm: pool www
16950 daemon 20 0 1731M 99420 54816 S 0.0 1.2 0:01.23 /opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /opt/bitnami/
16949 daemon 20 0 1731M 99420 54816 S 0.0 1.2 0:00.55 /opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /opt/bitnami/
=========================================
```

I notice that php-fpm www pool is taking a long time.

My last lines of my apache error logs:

```
54.36.108.162:43147] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: Unable to open /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/iconnect-mm.com/wp-content/wflogs/ips.php for reading and writing.\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:52:28.137313 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430372849408] [client 127.0.0.1:53566] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:52:28.138640 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430624630528] [client 127.0.0.1:53568] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:52:28.693027 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7264:tid 140430507132672] [client 163.172.66.247:60252] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: Unable to open /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/iconnect-mm.com/wp-content/wflogs/ips.php for reading and writing.\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:52:29.711571 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7264:tid 140430716950272] [client 54.36.108.162:43147] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: Unable to open /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/iconnect-mm.com/wp-content/wflogs/ips.php for reading and writing.\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:52:30.587409 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7264:tid 140430557488896] [client 163.172.66.247:60252] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: Unable to open /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/iconnect-mm.com/wp-content/wflogs/ips.php for reading and writing.\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:52:31.723761 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430844696320] [client 127.0.0.1:54172] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:52:31.938670 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7264:tid 140430674986752] [client 127.0.0.1:54204] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:52:32.752152 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430574274304] [client 199.249.230.64:5251] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: Unable to open /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/iconnect-mm.com/wp-content/wflogs/ips.php for reading and writing.\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:52:34.298572 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430716950272] [client 199.249.230.64:5561] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: Unable to open /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/iconnect-mm.com/wp-content/wflogs/ips.php for reading and writing.\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:04.738834 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430607845120] [client 199.249.230.64:5251] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: Unable to open /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/iconnect-mm.com/wp-content/wflogs/ips.php for reading and writing.\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:04.959442 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430481954560] [client 127.0.0.1:59048] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:04.960023 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430431598336] [client 127.0.0.1:41786] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:07.572530 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7264:tid 140430733735680] [client 127.0.0.1:59530] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:07.573123 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7256:tid 140430406420224] [client 127.0.0.1:42248] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:12.689832 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430725342976] [client 199.249.230.64:5251] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: Unable to open /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/iconnect-mm.com/wp-content/wflogs/ips.php for reading and writing.\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:12.691932 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7264:tid 140430255351552] [client 127.0.0.1:42634] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:12.772663 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7264:tid 140430532310784] [client 127.0.0.1:43364] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:12.778137 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7264:tid 140430591059712] [client 127.0.0.1:43378] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:12.783498 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7264:tid 140430827910912] [client 127.0.0.1:43380] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:12.790286 2019] [access_compat:error] [pid 7258:tid 140430616237824] [client 127.0.0.1:43382] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/xmlrpc.php
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:23.467214 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7264:tid 140430288922368] [client 185.220.101.27:45741] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: Unable to open /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/iconnect-mm.com/wp-content/wflogs/ips.php for reading and writing.\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:23.468534 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7256:tid 140430372849408] [client 127.0.0.1:33968] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:23.470151 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430532310784] [client 127.0.0.1:33982] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:23.471434 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7256:tid 140430356064000] [client 127.0.0.1:33984] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:23.472842 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7256:tid 140430339278592] [client 127.0.0.1:33986] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:26.680143 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430700164864] [client 84.17.47.136:63518] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: Unable to open /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/boltnutri.com/wp-content/wflogs/config-synced.php for reading and writing.\n', referer: http://boltnutri.com/
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:27.216602 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430633023232] [client 185.220.101.27:33981] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: Unable to open /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/iconnect-mm.com/wp-content/wflogs/ips.php for reading and writing.\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:29.015352 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7264:tid 140430339278592] [client 127.0.0.1:34504] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:30.522879 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7264:tid 140430819518208] [client 84.17.47.136:63815] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: Unable to open /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/boltnutri.com/wp-content/wflogs/config-synced.php for reading and writing.\n', referer: http://www.boltnutri.com/
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:30.569325 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430280529664] [client 127.0.0.1:34826] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:31.101313 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430819518208] [client 127.0.0.1:35102] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:31.102655 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7264:tid 140430381242112] [client 127.0.0.1:35202] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:31.103120 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7264:tid 140430557488896] [client 127.0.0.1:35220] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:31.104144 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7264:tid 140430674986752] [client 127.0.0.1:35222] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:31.105301 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430844696320] [client 127.0.0.1:35226] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:31.106564 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7264:tid 140430305707776] [client 127.0.0.1:35228] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:31.107907 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430574274304] [client 127.0.0.1:35230] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:31.109159 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7258:tid 140430591059712] [client 127.0.0.1:35232] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:45.256738 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430658201344] [client 127.0.0.1:37356] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:45.258327 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7258:tid 140430314100480] [client 127.0.0.1:37360] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:46.250021 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430599452416] [client 127.0.0.1:37554] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:46.251251 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430272136960] [client 127.0.0.1:37558] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:48.114389 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430557488896] [client 185.220.101.48:46339] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: Unable to open /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/iconnect-mm.com/wp-content/wflogs/ips.php for reading and writing.\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:51.980481 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430398027520] [client 51.15.43.205:51460] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: Unable to open /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/iconnect-mm.com/wp-content/wflogs/ips.php for reading and writing.\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:53.714783 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430481954560] [client 185.220.101.48:46339] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: Unable to open /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/iconnect-mm.com/wp-content/wflogs/ips.php for reading and writing.\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:54.474000 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430565881600] [client 51.15.43.205:51460] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: Unable to open /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/iconnect-mm.com/wp-content/wflogs/ips.php for reading and writing.\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:54.474970 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7264:tid 140430582667008] [client 127.0.0.1:50190] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:54.480284 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7264:tid 140430844696320] [client 127.0.0.1:50278] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:54.486058 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430431598336] [client 127.0.0.1:50280] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:54.491154 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7258:tid 140430515525376] [client 127.0.0.1:50282] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:54.496413 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430414812928] [client 127.0.0.1:50284] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:54.504865 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430322493184] [client 127.0.0.1:50288] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:54.509886 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430465169152] [client 127.0.0.1:50290] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:54.515117 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430364456704] [client 127.0.0.1:50292] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:54.520130 2019] [access_compat:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430674986752] [client 127.0.0.1:50294] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/xmlrpc.php
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:56.091301 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430811125504] [client 162.220.162.10:53928] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: Unable to open /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/iconnect-mm.com/wp-content/wflogs/ips.php for reading and writing.\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:59.277311 2019] [autoindex:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430624630528] [client 54.36.150.170:24672] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/ecd.gov.mm/sites/all/modules/ctools/ctools_custom_content/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Sun Aug 25 05:53:59.925716 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430827910912] [client 127.0.0.1:51606] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:54:00.121587 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430448383744] [client 127.0.0.1:51668] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:54:00.329811 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430255351552] [client 127.0.0.1:51716] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:54:00.556125 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430439991040] [client 127.0.0.1:51766] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:54:00.722575 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7264:tid 140430448383744] [client 127.0.0.1:51810] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:54:00.955556 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7264:tid 140430853089024] [client 127.0.0.1:51882] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:54:00.961745 2019] [access_compat:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430288922368] [client 127.0.0.1:51886] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/xmlrpc.php
[Sun Aug 25 05:54:18.482709 2019] [negotiation:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430473561856] [client 65.18.120.92:31071] AH00687: Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/umfccicentennialexpo.com/index.html (None could be negotiated)., referer: http://m.facebook.com/
[Sun Aug 25 05:54:29.695334 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430280529664] [client 127.0.0.1:42528] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Sun Aug 25 05:54:30.373033 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7246:tid 140430733735680] [client 127.0.0.1:42910] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
```

Comment: look at iotop and show what blocks the harddisk moreover we dont know what you are running on your machine and moreover htop is nice, but free -m & df -h tells us if your server lags on swap or free space

Comment: What are the two URL;s for your WordPress and Drupal web sites?  Would like to visit them.  There are two HTOP sessions running.  Do you exit Command Prompt gracefully when done with looking at your HTOP to release RAM used?  Why do you have FIVE of these entries? php-fpm: pool www  each one uses RAM.  The error log has definite PERMISSION problems listed that need to be resolved.  With LightSail can you use Performance Group maintenance to change ANY of your Global Variables?